# Expected identifier or "(" error

Tags: xcode

EDITED:  Thanks to your help I am closing in on the solution to my problem.  I have fixed the missing "@end error", and am left with just one "Expected identifier or "("" error.

This is the code, the error is noted:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] \
compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)


#import "WViewController.h"
#import <SkillzSDK-iOS/Skillz.h>

@interface WViewController ()

@end

@implementation WViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //create backdrop image
    NSMutableString *imgFile = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (![globalBackgroundImage isEqualToString:@""]) [imgFile setString:globalBackgroundImage]; //falls back to first image setting for all devices;
    if ((IS_WIDESCREEN_PHONE)&&(![widescreenBackgroundImage isEqualToString:@""])) [imgFile setString:widescreenBackgroundImage]; //you can specify a different image for
    if ((IS_IPAD)&&(![iPadBackgroundImage isEqualToString:@""])) [imgFile setString:iPadBackgroundImage]; //widescreen phones & for iPad
    if (![imgFile isEqualToString:@""]) {

        UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:imgFile] retain];

        CGSize imgSz = [img size];
        CGSize screenSz = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        float imgWH = imgSz.width/imgSz.height;
        float screenWH = screenSz.width/screenSz.height;

        CGRect backdropFrame;
        if (imgWH>=screenWH) backdropFrame = CGRectMake((screenSz.width/2)-((screenSz.height*imgWH)/2), 0, screenSz.height*imgWH, screenSz.height); //image wider than screen
        else backdropFrame = CGRectMake(0, ((screenSz.height/2)-((screenSz.width/imgWH)/2)), screenSz.width, screenSz.width/imgWH);

        UIImageView *backdropImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:backdropFrame];
        [backdropImageView setImage:img];
        [backdropImageView setAlpha:backgroundImageOpacity];
        [self.view addSubview:backdropImageView];
    }

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:globalBackgroundColor];


    //init GameCenter
    [[GameCenterManager sharedManager] setupManager];
    [[GameCenterManager sharedManager] setDelegate:self];

    //initialize the view for when the player is in the game
    gameView = [[WgameView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] fromViewController:self];
    [gameView setHidden:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:gameView];

    //initialize the view for then the player is on the home screen
    homeView = [[WhomeView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] fromViewController:self];
    [homeView setHidden:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:homeView];

}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //go to home screen right away
    [self goHome];

    //show a RevMob fullscreen ad if we're supposed to
    if (revMobActive) {
        if (showRevMobFullscreenOnLaunch) {
            [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
        }
    }
    //show a Chartboost ad if we're supposed to
    if (chartboostActive) {
        if (showChartboostOnLaunch) {
            [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
        }
    }

}


#pragma mark game flow


-(void) multiplayerButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Multiplayer button pressed, launching Skillz!");
    // Launching Skillz in landscape mode
    [[Skillz skillzInstance] launchSkillzForOrientation:SkillzLandscape
                                     launchHasCompleted:^{
                // This code is called after the Skillz UI launches.
                NSLog(@"Skillz just launched.");
            } tournamentWillBegin:^(NSDictionary *gameRules) {
                // This code is called when a player starts a game in the Skillz portal.
                NSLog(@"Tournament with rules: %@", gameRules);
                NSLog(@"Now starting a game…");

                                         // INCLUDE CODE HERE TO START YOUR GAME
                                         // …..
                                         // …..
                                         // …..
                                         // END OF CODE TO START GAME


                                     } skillzWillExit:^{
                                      // This code is called when exiting the Skillz portal
                                         //back to the normal game.
                                         NSLog(@"Skillz exited.");
                                     }];

}

- (void) startGame:(UIButton*)sender {

    //hide RevMob banner ad if we're supposed to
    if (revMobActive) {
        if (showRevMobBannerOnHomeScreen) {
            [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];
        }
    }

    //starts game in the mode corresponding to which button was tapped
    [[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] setCurrentGameMode:sender.titleLabel.text];
    [gameView startGame];
    [homeView setHidden:YES];
    [gameView setHidden:NO];

    //init timer if timed game
    if ([[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] isTimedGame]) {
        timedGameTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(decrementTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
    }

    //notify game engine to play sound if configured
    [[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] soundEventDidHappen:@"BeginGame"];

}



- (void) goHomeButtonPressed {
    [self stopGame];
    [self goHome];
}

- (void) stopGame {

    //stop timer if this was a timed game
    if (timedGameTimer) {
        [timedGameTimer invalidate];
        [timedGameTimer release];
        timedGameTimer=nil;
    }
}


- (void) goHome {
    [gameView setHidden:YES];
    [homeView setHidden:NO];

    //show a RevMob banner ad if we're supposed to
    if (revMobActive) {
        if (showRevMobBannerOnHomeScreen) {
            [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
        }
    }
}

- (void) decrementTime {
    [[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] timeDecreased]; //report to our game model that time has decreased
    if ([[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] timeLeft]<=0) { //if 0 seconds left,
        [self timedGameEnded]; //game has ended
    }
    if (([[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] timeLeft]<6)&&([[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] timeLeft]>0)) {
        //notify game engine to play sound if configured
        [[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] soundEventDidHappen:@"FiveSecondCountdown"];
    }
    [gameView updateLabels]; //update gameView's score and time labels
}


- (void) timedGameEnded {
    //game over!
    [self stopGame];

    //notify game engine to play sound if configured
    [[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] soundEventDidHappen:@"GameOver"];

    //show an alert with score and list of words found (if you want, you can add a whole separate screen for this instead of simple alert!)
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Game Over" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d points!\n\nWords found:\n%@",[[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] getScore],[[[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] getWordsFound] componentsJoinedByString:@" "]] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    //report score to GameCenter
    int sc = [[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] getScore];
    if (sc>0) [self reportScore:sc forCategory:[[[[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] getCurrentGameMode] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] componentsJoinedByString:@"_"]];

    [@"com.bundle.appname" stringByAppendingString:[[[[[WGameModeEngine sharedInstance] getCurrentGameMode] lowercaseString] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];
}


- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //share latest score on Facebook if we're supposed to
    if (FacebookShareEnabled) {[self facebookShare];}

    //go to home screen
    [self goHome];

    //show a RevMob fullscreen ad if we're supposed to
    if (revMobActive) {
        if (showRevMobFullscreenWhenGameOver) {
            [[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
        }
    }
    //show a Chartboost ad if we're supposed to
    if (chartboostActive) {
        if (showChartboostWhenGameOver) {
            [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
        }
    }
}


#pragma mark GameCenter



- (void)gameCenterManager:(GameCenterManager *)manager authenticateUser:(UIViewController *)gameCenterLoginController {
    if (revMobActive) {
        if (showRevMobBannerOnHomeScreen) {
            [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];
        }
    }

    [self presentViewController:gameCenterLoginController animated:YES completion:^(void)
     {if (revMobActive) {
        if (showRevMobBannerOnHomeScreen) {
            [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
        }}}];
}



if (isGameOver) {<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ERROR IS HERE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    if ([[Skillz skillzInstance] tournamentIsInProgress]) {
        // The game ended and it was in a Skillz tournament,
        // so report the score and go back to Skillz.
        [[Skillz skillzInstance] completeTurnWithGameData:gameData
                                              playerScore:playerScore
                                  playerCurrentTotalScore:playerCurrentTotalScore
                                opponentCurrentTotalScore:opponentCurrentTotalScore
                                             roundOutcome:turnOutcome
                                             matchOutcome:matchOutcome
                                           withCompletion:^{
                                               // Code in this block is called when exiting to Skillz
                                               // and reporting the score.
                                               NSLog(@"Reporting score to Skillz…");
                                           }];
    } else {
        // Otherwise single player game, so take the normal action
    }
}

- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am really new to coding and hoping that someone can help me with what I am sure is a very simple problem. I have looked at a lot of other answers regarding this error, but they don't seem to apply to my situation.

The following code is part of a game app I am working on using Xcode, trying to integrate it with a third party system called SKILLZ.  I did not write any of the code and am trying to understand it as I proceed with the integration.

I have noted within the code where I am getting the error:

```
    #import "WAppDelegate.h"
    #import "WViewController.h"
    #import <SkillzSDK-iOS/Skillz.h>

    @implementation WAppDelegate

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [_window release];
        [_viewController release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    {
        //initialize language engine
        [WLanguageEngine sharedInstance];

        //initialize game mode engine
        [WGameModeEngine sharedInstance];

        //initialize RevMob
        if (revMobActive) {
            [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:RevMobAppID];
        }

        if (revMobActive&&revMobTestingMode) {
            [RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithAds;
            // or
            //[RevMobAds session].testingMode = RevMobAdsTestingModeWithoutAds;
        }

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[[WViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }


    {<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**<<EXPECTED IDENTIFIER OR "(">>  ERROR OCCURS HERE**
        // INITIALIZE SKILLZ HERE
        // 940 is the game ID that was given to us by the Skillz Developer Portal.
        // SkillzSandbox specifies that we will use the sandbox server since we
        // are still developing the game.
        // SkillzProduction specifies that we will use the production server since
        // the game is ready for release to the AppStore
        [[Skillz skillzInstance] skillzInitForGameId:@"940"
                                         environment:SkillzSandbox];


I am getting a second occurrence of this error in a different part of the app code, but am hoping that if I can sort this one out that it will help me to understand the other.

Hoping that this is not off-topic or too specific, and that someone might be able to help.

Cheers
Jen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**<>  ERROR OCCURS HERE**
    // INITIALIZE SKILLZ HERE
    // 940 is the game ID that was given to us by the Skillz Developer Portal.
    // SkillzSandbox specifies that we will use the sandbox server since we
    // are still developing the game.
    // SkillzProduction specifies that we will use the production server since
    // the game is ready for release to the AppStore
    [[Skillz skillzInstance] skillzInitForGameId:@"940"
                                     environment:SkillzSandbox];

```
return YES;
```

}

This block is outside of `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Perhaps you forgot a declaration or added an extraneous `}` somewhere

Comment: Thanks @Antzi. I moved the block into what I think is the right place, and it solved the problem. Except now I am getting a "Missing @end" error at the end of the code, where there is clearly an "@end".  When I put another one in, it gives me another error that says "@end must appear in and ObcjectiveC context".   Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I am closing in on it.  I have fixed the missing end error, and am left with just one Expected identifier or "(" error.

Comment: @JenCooper Indent your code (select all text, then menu editor => structure => indent). You should be able to see the problem easily (probably an extraneous `}`)